# Sink From Apache flink to Ignite which is located in a remote server

Tags: ignite, flink-streaming

I am using flink as the stream processor in my application, and I want to dump the result in apache ignite which is located in a remote server. in TcpDiscoverySpi part of the ignite.xml, I specified the ip address of the ignite server; however, no connection ever stablishes to the server.
this is my ignite.xml:

```
<property name="discoverySpi">
           <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
               <property name="ipFinder">
                   <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                       <property name="addresses">
                           <list>
                               <value>remoteIpAddress:47500</value>
                           </list>
                       </property>
                   </bean>
               </property>
           </bean>
       </property>
```

I used the below link as the igniteSink class:
https://github.com/bpark/flink-ignite-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/bpark/IgniteSink.java

And the below code in order to sink stream to ignite:

```
private void sinkToCache(DataStream<Map<String,String>> dsRow){
        IgniteSink<Map<String,String>> igniteSink = new IgniteSink<>();
        //igniteSink.start();
        igniteSink.setAllowOverwrite(true);
        igniteSink.setAutoFlushFrequency(10);
        dsRow.addSink(igniteSink);
    }
```

Here is the dependendies:

```
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-indexing</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-flink</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-log4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Unfortunately, no connection stablishes to the server as I see the server's log. I am pretty sure that there is no problem with the port, also no issue in the firewall as I can telnet the server and see the log of stablished Tcp connection from my pc to the server in logs.
Any idea what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Did you call `execute()` on the StreamExecutionEnvironment? Have you tried to `print()` the stream instead, to ensure the job works at all?

Comment: Please provide logs. There should be clear indication that Ignite node tries to start.

Comment: yes, the execute works well, and the print also works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could finally figure out the issue by changing the code in sinkToCache, so that it started in clientMode.

here is my client node configuration:

```
TcpDiscoverySpi spi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
        spi.setAckTimeout(500);
        spi.setSocketTimeout(2000);
        TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder();
        List<String> address = new java.util.ArrayList<> 
  (Collections.singletonList("remoteIpAddress:47500..47509"));
       
        ipFinder.setAddresses(address);

        //spi.setIpFinder(ipFinder);
        spi.setLocalPort(47500);
        TcpCommunicationSpi commSpi = new TcpCommunicationSpi();
        commSpi.setLocalPort(47100);
        commSpi.setSlowClientQueueLimit(3000);
        IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();

        // Override default discovery SPI.
        cfg.setDiscoverySpi(spi);
        cfg.setFailureHandler(new StopNodeFailureHandler());
        cfg.setCommunicationSpi(commSpi);
        cfg.setClientMode(true);
        Ignition.start(cfg);
```